# Method GetAppInfoByName does not exist?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, csom

I am trying out the tenant APIs towards an on-premise SharePoint 2013 Server install. This server is up to the October 2015 CU.

I following the guidance on Vesa's [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/06/09/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-model-in-on-premises-with-just-csom.aspx):

I registered the server-stub and restarted the W3SVC and WAS services and set the `AdministrationSiteType` to `TenantAdministration`.

Then I try out the following PowerShell fragment to enumerate all available add-ins in the app catalog:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\SharePoint Client Components\Assemblies\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll'
$siteUrl = "http://sharepoint2013.local" 
$ctx = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$tenant = new-object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant($ctx)
$coll = $tenant.GetAppInfoByName([string]::Empty)
$tenant.Context.Load($coll)
$tenant.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

> The method GetAppInfoByName does not exist.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you try some string value instead of `[string]::Empty` in `GetAppInfoByName`

Comment: @AtishDipongkor empty string is used probably to get all apps.

Comment: @Unnie could be. but I did not find in *MSDN*. I hope you have other reference. then please share. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.getappinfobyname.aspx